# An example of sum that is not direct

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, direct-sum

Give an example of $V_1, V_2, V_3\subset W$ where $V_i\cap V_j=\{0\}$ for every $i\ne j$ yet the sum $V_1+V_2+V_3$ is not direct.

My answer: Let $W=\mathbb{R}^3$, $V_1=\{(x,2x,0):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $V_2=\{(x,3x,0):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\},V_3=\{(x,4x,0):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$. All are subspaces, but $V_1+V_2+V_3\ne\mathbb{R}^3$ hence it is not a direct sum.

Am I correct?

Comment: In your example, $V_1,V_2$, and $V_3$ are all the $xy$ plane since for instance $2y$ runs over $\mathbb{R}$ as $y$ does.

Comment: Can you give an answer

Comment: GAVD's answer is a good start: choose three distinct non-zero vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $V_i=\mathrm{span}(v_i)$.

Comment: Why can't we consider $\mathbb{R}^3$? What's the difference? What criteria of direct sum are you using?

Comment: A similar example would work in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: What do you mean a similar example? So is my answer correct?

Comment: Your choice of subspaces will work, though as carmichael561 indicates, you might as well work in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, your argument about why it is not a direct sum isn't really right. If you used analogous subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $V_1+V_2+V_3=\mathbb{R}^2$, but the sum is still not direct.

Comment: Can I argue that the representation of vectors in the space is not unique? Thereby the sum is not direct?

Comment: That would be one way. But my personal recommendation would be to show that the definition fails. It will help reinforce why the definition is the way it is, which I suspect is the main point of the exercise.

Comment: Of course your suggestion may be following my advice, depending on the definition of direct sum with multiple summands you're working with.

Comment: My first definition of direct sum is product space with coordinatewise operations. But how should i proceed from that??

Comment: You should have a different definition for the direct sum of subspaces.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take three lines passing through $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Can you explain more? Why should I take them in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Isn't the sum is not direct now?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, an example would be U= (x,y,0) and W= (0,x,z)
U+W is a Subspace sum but it is NOT A DIRECT SUBSPACE SUM that is because, it is obvious that U spans x and y place let u = (2,1,0), then in order to span the last place we need a free moving z but x must be kept at 0, the existence of x means that there is an extra degree of freedom and the direct sum requirement is violated as two possibilities can yield the same vector in W+U when the x in W is adjusted against the y In U

Note that your answer is not correct, the trick in this section is that the x and the y might be but not necessarily the same everywhere but must be the same next to each other and the direct sum requires each element to be mapped by a unique additive combination of these lists, the lists you answered do not sum to produce R³ let alone direct sum.....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).